# Binary, Floats, and Modern Computers

Tags: c, binary, floating-point, hardware, computer-science

I have been reading a lot about floats and computer-processed floating-point operations. The biggest question I see when reading about them is why are they so inaccurate? I understand this is because binary cannot accurately represent all real numbers, so the numbers are rounded to the 'best' approximation.

My question is, knowing this, why do we still use binary as the base for computer operations? Surely using a larger base number than 2 would increase the accuracy of floating-point operations exponentially, would it not?

What are the advantages of using a binary number system for computers as opposed to another base, and has another base ever been tried? Or is it even possible?

Comment: because a switch can only be on or off, and a computer is a bunch of really small switches.

Comment: This has actually been studied and has some theoretical advantages. You might want to look up "multiple-valued logic circuits" for example.

Comment: decimal is also inacurate - you can't present 1/3 as decimal, for example.

Comment: Actually, there is no floating point base that would allow all numbers to have a finite representation. Base-10 has things like 1/3, 1/7, etc. (rational numbers) and *e* and *pi* (non-rational numbers) that don't have finite representations either. The better question is how much accuracy do you need for your particular problem - can you use a float, or do you need a double (or even a long double, for those compilers that support them)?

Comment: @twalberg Precisely. The only truly accurate notation of all numbers number is the description of how to achieve that number. Which, in a fun twist of logic, renders the notation somewhat pointless!

Comment: If you really need to, you can emulate other bases in software (for example, you can trivially, and inefficiently, represent a base 3 number in binary by converting each 0 to 00, each 1 to 01, and each 2 to 10).  In fact, lots of software packages are capable of this - in financial applications, it is often necessary to round results to a decimal approximation.

Comment: Historically some chips (notably the Motorola 68k series) have had hardware support for coding two decimal digits in a binary octet (a practice called BCD for binary coded decimal) and performing arithmetic on such numbers.

Comment: @Polynomial: Note that the subset of real numbers that can be described by giving a way to construct them is countable, since algorithms are countable.  So actually [almost all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) real numbers cannot be described in *any way whatsoever*.

Comment: @SvenMarnach True, but in practice (certainly in programming) we can only really use numbers that we have a way of representing, whether it be via a set of numeric digits or an algorithm/equation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Computers are built on transistors, which have a "switched on" state, and a "switched off" state. This corresponds to high and low voltage. Pretty much all digital integrated circuits work in this binary fashion.

Ignoring the fact that transistors just simply work this way, using a different base (e.g. base 3) would require these circuits to operate at an intermediate voltage state (or several) as well as 0V and their highest operating voltage. This is more complicated, and can result in problems at high frequencies - how can you tell whether a signal is just transitioning between 2V and 0V, or actually at 1V?

When we get down to the floating point level, we are (as nhahtdh mentioned in their answer) mapping an infinite space of numbers down to a finite storage space. It's an absolute guarantee that we'll lose some precision. One advantage of IEEE floats, though, is that the precision is relative to the magnitude of the value.

Update: You should also check out [Tunguska](http://tunguska.sourceforge.net/), a ternary computer emulator. It uses base-3 instead of base-2, which makes for some interesting (albeit mind-bending) concepts.

Comment: So, theoretically, if we could find a way to accurately distinguish between these voltages, it would be possible/advantageous?

Comment: Potentially, but it brings a whole range of electrical engineering problems with it. Digital signals are essentially AC voltage sources, which are affected by electromagnetic interference from physically local lines. All copper on the board that has a high frequency digital signal going through it is essentially a patch antenna. Having multiple voltage levels makes distiortion and spikes much more painful to deal with.

Comment: We already have difficulty detecting the difference between 1 and 0 in multi-GHz systems (it's why you have to overvolt overclocked processors), so making the distinction less obvious amplifies the problem. Quantum and photon-based computers *may* move us away from these issues in future, but for now we'll be sticking to traditional binary transistors.

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios: using voltage levels to represent numbers is an aspect of *analog computers*.  These used (50 years ago) to be much more common than they are today.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks guys!

Comment: This is correct in what it says, but does not address the real issue which is that increasing the base has no effect on accuracy of representation.  You can increase precision only by increasing the storage allocated (i.e. more bits, 'trits', hexadecimal digits, base-100 "cents", etc)

Comment: I think you meant triggers. Transistor is stateless.

Comment: @Andrey I was being simplistic, since OP seems not to be familiar with EE terms.

Comment: @JimGarrison True, but that was already covered by ArjunShankar's answer. I had a feeling that OP was looking for a technical reason as to why we don't use higher bases, and simply tried to use floating point as an (albeit invalid) example.

Comment: @Polynomial if he is not then both words will make not much sense for him, but using correct words is important, that's my opinion.

Comment: 729 states per tryte? Ugh... 256 states per byte is a perfectly round number. Who'd want anything else? :)

Comment: @AllonGuralnek The number 256 has just been drilled into our minds so much. Had we started with trinary, it'd be as natural as binary.

Comment: @Polynomial: Yeah, it was a joke. Each number base has its own 'round' numbers.

Answer (score 37):

First of all: You cannot represent all real numbers even when using say, base 100. But you already know this. Anyway, this means: Inaccuracy will always arise due to 'not being able to represent all real numbers'.

Now lets talk about **"*what* can higher bases bring to you when doing math?":** Higher bases bring exactly **'nothing'** in terms of precision. Why?

If you want to use base 4, then a 16 digit base 4 number provides exactly 4<sup>16</sup> different values.

*But you can get the same number of different values from a 32 digit base 2 number* (2<sup>32</sup> = 4<sup>16</sup>).

As another answer already said: Transistors can either be on or off. So your newly designed base 4 registers need to be an abstraction over (base 2) ON/OFF 'bits'. This means: Use two 'bits' to represent a base 4 digit. But you'll *still* get exactly 2<sup>N</sup> levels by spending N 'bits' (or N/2 base-4 digits). **You can only get better accuracy by spending *more bits*, not by increasing the base**. Which base you 'imagine/abstract' your numbers to be in (e.g. like how `printf` can print these base-2 numbers in base-10) is really just a matter of abstraction and not precision.

Answer (score 12):

We are essentially mapping a finite space to an infinite set of real number. So it is not even a problem of base anyway.

Base 2 is chosen, like Polynomial said, for implementation reason, as it is easier to differentiate 2 levels of energy.

We either throw more space to represent more numbers/increase precision, or limit the range that we want to encode, or a mix of them.

Answer (score 6):

Your first paragraph makes sense but the second is a non-sequiter. A larger base would not make a difference to the precision.

The precison of a number depends on the amount of storage that is used for it - for example a 16 bit binary number has the same precision as a 2 x 256 base number - both take up the same amount of information.

See the [Usual floating point reference.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more detail - and it generalises to all bases.

Yes computers have been built using other bases - I know of ones that use base 10 (decimal) cf [wikipaedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_computer)

Answer (score 6):

It boils out to getting the most from available chip area.

If you use on/off switches to represent numbers, you can't get more precision per switch than with a base-2 representation. This is simply because N switches can represent 2^N quantities no matter what you choose these values to be. There were early machines that used base 16 floating point digits, but each of these needed 4 binary bits, so the overall precision per bit was the same as base 2 (actually somewhat less due to edge cases).

If you choose a base that's not a power of 2, precision is obviously lost. For example you need 4 bits to represent one decimal digit, but 6 of the available values of those 4 bits are never used.  This system is called binary-coded decimal and it's still used occassionally, usually when doing computations with money.

Multi-level logic could efficiently implement other bases, but at least with current chip technologies, it turns out to be very expensive to implement more than 2 levels.  Even quantum computers are being design assuming two quantum levels: quantum bits or qubits.

The nature of the world and math is what makes the floating point situation hopeless. There is a hierarchy of real numbers  Integer -> Rational -> Algebraic -> Transendental. There's a wonderful mathematical proof, Cantor diagonalization, that most numbers, i.e. a "bigger infinity" than the other sets, are Transdendental.  Yet no matter what floating point system you choose, there will still be lowly *rational* numbers with no perfect representation (i.e. 1/3 in base 10). This is our universe.  No amount of clever hardware design will change it.

Software can and does use rational representations, storing a numerator and denominator as integers.  However with these your programmer's hands are tied.  For example, square root is not "closed."  Sqrt(2) has no rational representation.

There has been research with algebraic number reps and "lazy" reps of arbitrary reals that produce more digits as needed.  Most work of this type seems to be in computational geometry.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are/have been computers that use other than binary (i.e., other than base 2 representations and aritmetic):
[Decimal computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_computer).

Designers of computing systems have looked into many alternatives. But it's hard to find a model that's as simple to implement in a physical device than one using two discrete states. So start with a binary circuit that's very easy and cheap to build and work up to a computer with complex operations. That's  the history of binary in a nutshell.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a EE, so everything I say below may be totally wrong.  But...

The advantage of binary is that it maps very cleanly to distinguishing between on/off (or, more accurately, high/low voltage) states in real circuits.  Trying to distinguish between multiple voltages would, I think, present a bit more of a challenge.

This may go completely out the window if quantum computers make it out of the lab.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues arising from the use of binary floating-point numbers to represent mathematical real numbers -- well, there are probably a lot more issues, but 2 is enough for the time being.

1. All computer numbers are finite so any number which requires an
   infinite number of digits cannot be accurately represented on a
   computer, whatever number base is chosen.  So that deals with pi, e,
   and most of the other real numbers.
2. Whatever base is chosen will have difficulties representing (finitely) some fractions.  Base 2 can only approximate any fraction with a factor of 3 in the denominator, but base 5 or base 7 do too.

Over the years computers with circuitry based on devices with more than 2 states have been built.  The old Soviet Union developed a series of computers with 3-state devices and at least one US computer manufacturer at one time offered computers using 10-state devices for arithmetic.

I suspect that binary representation has won out (so far) because it is simple, both to reason about and to implement with current electronic devices.

Answer (score 0):

I vote that we move to a Rational number system storage.  Two 32 bit intergers that will evaluate as p/q.  Multiplication and division will be really cheap operations.  Yeah there will be redundant evaluated numbers (1/2 = 2/4), but who really uses the full dynamic range of a 64 bit double anyways.

Comment: How will this speed up multiplication? Each multiply becomes two multiplies (Now both numerator and denominator must be multiplied, albeit independently; so they can be done in parallel). Each division also becomes two multiplies (which, I admit, is typically somewhat better than one divide). Also, each time you multiply or divide, you need to check for overflow and adjust. e.g. If I did ((((1 / 2) * 2) / 2) * 2) .. and so on, a few times, eventually, both the numerator and denominator will overflow. A regular binary float won't have this trouble because 1/2 is representable exactly.

Comment: And addition/subtraction becomes a nightmare. Not only do you need to equalize the denominators before you add the numerators, you also need to take care of signedness.

Comment: Nonetheless, this is an interesting thought!

Comment: I know this is my fourth comment. But your idea reminded me of a weird little number system they taught us in Computer Arithmetic class. It's called the ["residue number system"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_number_system) (RNS), and it is intended to make addition and multiplication cheap. I expect it goes into some ASICs.

Comment: another bonus would be that this breaks down into all integer math.  So if for some reason your system has really poor floating point performance, this might be better.

Answer (score -2):

I'm neither an electrical engineer nor a mathematician, so take that into consideration when I make the following statement:

**All floating point numbers can be represented as integers.**

Comment: And the latter is an infinite integer, which cannot possibly be stored to its fullest precision, even if you encoded one digit on every particle in the universe.

Comment: If you kept chaining each level of precision indefinitely, e.g.: in a database, you should be able to get the increase in precision, no?

Comment: No. Pi is an irrational number. The only truly accurate representation of Pi is a description of how to calculate it. Representing it in any base encoding would require infinite precision and therefore infinite storage space.

Comment: @ArjunShankar: Point taken. Thinking again, there is nothing wrong with the statement in the answer, as floating point number's space is finite. But the statement also doesn't have any value anyway.

Comment: Floating point numbers can be represented as _two_ integers. Either in the theoretical sense (where both the FP and INT can have infinite length) or in the computer sense (where both have fixed length). The two components are known as exponent and mantissa.

Comment: according to Wikipedia, a floating point number is a representation of a real number. Pi is a real number. But even if we just consider rational numbers (which can be represented as a/b, where a and b are integers), you could not represent any rational number between 0 and 1 in a computer.